# Вставка в heapq по ключу

Tags: python, алгоритм, heap

Изучил документацию [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#module-heapq), но не могу понять как добавить в кучу словарь и указать по какому значению он должен сравниваться с другими значениями. Я могу использовать встроенный `sort` и использовать параметр `key`, но мне нужен `heapq`. Нужно писать свою реализацию или есть какой-то аналог этой библиотеки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставлять кортежи, первый элемент которых - сравниваемое значение, а второй - словарь

```
heapq.heappush(h, (1, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}))
```

Comment: В итоге в куче будут храниться кортежи, да?

Comment: Да, а в них словари.